# JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, java-home

#### Steps to reproduce

- Error.

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I went to this directory and found

[image]

- I have changed the default JAVA_HOME path to
  [image]

[image]

- after changing the defalut java home path, i still get this error.

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

#### Code sample

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

#### Expected results

The Default JAVA-HOME path should change in android studio too, since i have changed it on my computer.
at least that what i think should happen.

#### Actual results

I get the same error which contain the previous directory

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is solved by Upgrading the Flutter SDK

```
flutter upgrade
```